# Django channels - not connection to ws

Tags: python, django, websocket

I'm making an example from the documentation Django channels and it works great!

I see in the logs

```
HTTP GET /chat/lobby/ 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:43164]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:43168]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:43168]
```

however I can't connect with the wscat client

```
andrey@andrey-desktop:~$ wscat -c "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/lobby/"
error: Unexpected server response: 403
```

or postman -
[postman disconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EOC.png)

I see in the logs on unsuccessful attempts

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:43232]
WebSocket REJECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:43232]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:43232]
```

How do I make connectivity from other clients, not just from the javascript/html page?

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have set `AllowedHostsOriginValidator` in asgi.py.
If you do, you need to send `Origin` in your headers.
If localhost, `Origin` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.